# Velocity PagerTool is creating incorrect links in my pagination

Tags: java, pagination, velocity

I'm trying to use the velocity PagerTool to add pagination to my velocity template. I followed the instructions on their website and even used their sample code. I populate the pager items and set the number of items per page in my controller before forwarding to my template.

Everything "looks" like it worked when I navigate to that page, however, when I click on the pagination numbers it doesn't work. I know my items made it to the pager because it displays the items on the page correctly.

The pagination looks like this:
< 1 2 3 4 5 6 >

When I click on 1 it refreshes the page and displays a different set of values for the page. When I click on anything greater than 1, it breaks. Any ideas?

I'm guessing I'm either not using the links correctly (even though I did it exactly as they said to) or there is something I'm not populating correctly in my controller.

Here's what I have in my controller:

```
PagerTool pager = new PagerTool();
pager.setItemsPerPage(10);
pager.setItems(myListOfItems);
request.setAttribute("pager", pager);           
request.setAttribute("new.items", myListOfItems);
```

I used the code from the sample they gave in the docs: [PagerTool][1]

Here's the code I'm using in my vm template:

```
   #if( $pager.hasItems() )
   Showing $!pager.pageDescription<br>
     #set( $i = $pager.index )
     #foreach( $item in $pager.page )
       ${i}. $!item <br>
       #set( $i = $i + 1 )
     #end
     <br>
     #if ( $pager.pagesAvailable > 1 )
       #set( $pagelink = $link.self.param("show",$!pager.itemsPerPage) )
       #if( $pager.prevIndex )
           <a href="$pagelink.param('index',$!pager.prevIndex)">Prev</a>
       #end
       #foreach( $index in $pager.slip )
         #if( $index == $pager.index )
           <b>$pager.pageNumber</b>
         #else
           <a href="$pagelink.param('index',$!index)">$!pager.getPageNumber($index)</a>
         #end
       #end
       #if( $pager.nextIndex )
           <a href="$pagelink.param('index',$!pager.nextIndex)">Next</a>
       #end
     #end
   #else
   No items in list.
   #end
```

I've searched all over for the answers but haven't found anything that works yet. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are manually configuring the tool instead of having VelocityTools do it.  That is fine, but then you must call (in java) pager.setup(request); on every request, so that it knows what page you are on and all that.

Comment: I would prefer to have VelocityTools auto configure it for me but this was the only way I could find to do it. Can you tell me how to have Velocity handle it for me.

So, the way I have it right now, I would need to call pager.setup and pass in the request object every time a link is clicked on?

Comment: VelocityTools has a showcase application that demonstrates having it auto-managed.  And yes, it needs to know about each request, as it is a request-scope tool.

Answer (score 0):

I am using velocity & velocity tools 2.0 with SSH. I encountered issues when I used PagerTool and LinkTool. I could not generate the correct pagination link. Here is my code:

```
  Page<User> userList = (Page<User>) userService.getUserList(user, pageInfo);
    PagerTool pager = new PagerTool();
    pager.setItemsPerPage(1);
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    list.addAll(userList.getPageElements());
    pager.setItems(list);
    ServletActionContext.getRequest().setAttribute("new.items", list);
    ActionContext.getContext().put("pager", pager);
```

I did not know how to use the LinkTool.